# Given the dimension of a vector space $V$ and the minimal polynomial of an operator $T$, what are the invariant factors?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Assume $V$ is a complex $6$-dimensional vector space and $T$ is a linear operator on $V$. Assume that the minimal polynomial is $(x + 2i)^3$ What are all the possible Jordan canonical forms for $T$?

In order to determine the Jordan canonical forms, we list the invariant factors.

The possibilites for the invariant factors are:

$(x + 2i)^3,(x+2i)^3$

$(x + 2i)^3, (x+2i)^2,(x+2i)$

$(x+2i)^3,(x+2i),(x+2i),(x+2i)$

Question: Why couldn't we have $(x+2i)^2,(x+2i)^2,(x+2i)^2$ or $(x+2i),(x+2i),(x+2i),(x+2i),(x+2i),(x+2i)$ as possible invariant factors? In either case, the product of the invariant factors yields the characteristic polynomial and each invariant factor divides the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial is the largest (in terms of divisibility) invariant factor (of the $\Bbb C[X]$-module associated to $V$ and $T$). Therefore it must occur in your list, and the others (needed to make the total degree $6$) must be divisors of your minimal polynomial.